# Ruby: adding multiple rows to a hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a class that looks like this:

```
class VariableStack
  def initialize(document)
    @document = document
  end

  def to_array
    @document.template.stacks.each { |stack| stack_hash stack }
  end

  private

  def stack_hash(stack)
    stack_hash = {}
    stack_hash['stack_name'] = stack.name
    stack_hash['boxes'] = [stack.boxes.each { |box| box_hash box }]
    stack_hash
  end

  def box_hash(box)
    box_hash = {}
    content = []

    box.template_variables.indexed.each { |var| content << content_array(var) }
    content.delete_if(&:blank?)
    box_hash.store('content', content.join("\n"))
    return if box_hash['content'].empty?
    box_hash
  end

  def content_array(var)
    v = @document.template_variables.where(master_id: var.id).first
    return unless v

    if v.text.present?
      v.format_text
    elsif v.photo_id.present?
      v.image.uploaded_image.url
    end
  end
end
```

The document I'm testing with has two `template_variables` so the desired result should be a nested hash like so:

Instead I'm getting this result:

```
 => [#<Stack id: 1, name: "User information">]
```

i.e., I'm not getting the `boxes` key nor it's nested content. Why isn't my method looping through the `box_hash` and `content` fields?

Comment: By the way: the conversion methods for arrays are called `to_a` and `to_ary`, not `to_array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `to_array` method uses `each` method, which returns the object it's been called on (in this case `@document.template.stacks`)

Change it to the `map` and you may get the desired result:

```
def to_array
  @document.template.stacks.map { |stack| stack_hash stack }
end
```

Comment: Ah, so simple! I knew I was close. Thanks so much.